# Dynamic Configuration of Script Task in SSIS

Tags: configuration, ssis, configure

I have to execute a VB script on some data from a CRM database in a data flow task. I want to make it configurable on other system as well.

I am able to assign the connection string of the connection manager dynamically by configuring through variable using a configuration file. Is there any way to configure the ScriptLink property of Script Component Editor so that I can make the address of the script dynamic.

[image]

I have also tried CozyRoc Script Task + also but am still confused. I will highly appreciate any help.

Comment: Can you give an example of the configuration you would want to do with regard to the script task?

Comment: Actually  I have a number of scripts. I wish to assign the path of the folder(containing scripts) to a variable mapped to config file and concatenate the value with the script name. Thus using the address dynamically on a different machine.

Comment: Still not sure I'm following, perhaps it's my ignorance of the CozyRoc components. You have `Script1.cs` and `Script2.cs` and you can manually change which script you use. The desire then is to allow that choice to be set through expressions.

Comment: Yes I exactly meant that. However by looking over I found out that we can't use expressions in the script component editor in a data flow task but the SciptLink property can be mapped to configuration file. Hence one way is to link the address paths of the each of the scripts to the configuration file. Folder path can not be set. Thanks for looking!